# Show bullets in parbix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, wrap, bullets, box

I am trying to add bullets to each item. However, the itemize isnt showing the bullets. Could someone tell me what the issu is?

Also how do I get the item to automatically fill the box and wrap?

```
% EPC flow charts
% Author: Fabian Schuh
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title:  EPC flow charts
:Grid: 1x2


\end{comment}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           minimum height=2em,
           inner sep=2pt,
           text centered,
           },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth']

 % Position of QUERY 
 % Use previously defined 'state' as layout (see above)
 % use tabular for content to get columns/rows
 % parbox to limit width of the listing
 \node[state] (QUERY) 
 {\begin{tabular}{l}
  \textbf{Query}\\
  \parbox{4cm}{\begin{itemize}
   \item Start
   \item Parameter $Q$
   \item Zufallszahl aus \mbox{$[0, 2^Q-1]$} in Slotzähler $SC$
  \end{itemize}
  }\\[4em]
  \textbf{QueryAdjust}\\
  \parbox{4cm}{\begin{itemize}
   \item Variiere Q
   \item neue Zufallszahl
  \end{itemize}
  }
 \end{tabular}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem here (with bullets showing). Can you include a picture of the output? Are you getting any warnings? Note that you should avoid using the `minimal` document class.

Comment: The bullets do also not show on my TeXLive 2017 distribution, but if I follow @Werner and change the document class to, say, article, they do. But I am actually more concerned about how you use tabular and so on here. None of this is necessary.

Comment: The problem is exactly in using the `minimal` class that does no definition to `\labelitemi` (besides not defining several other things).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any of the tabular, parbox and so on, I think. And if you choose a different document class, the bullets will show.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title:  EPC flow charts
:Grid: 1x2


\end{comment}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           minimum height=2em,
           inner sep=2pt,
           text centered,
           },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth']

 % Position of QUERY 
 % Use previously defined 'state' as layout (see above)
 % use tabular for content to get columns/rows
 % parbox to limit width of the listing
 \node[state,text width=4cm,align=left] (QUERY) 
 {\textbf{Query}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item Start
   \item Parameter $Q$
   \item Zufallszahl aus $[0, 2^Q-1]$ in Slotz\"ahler $SC$
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace*{0.2cm} %<- if you really want to have these vertical spaces, you can   get them like this
  \textbf{QueryAdjust}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item Variiere Q
   \item neue Zufallszahl
  \end{itemize} 
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want all these vertical spaces, you may work with `\vspace`.